# Use angularjs ng-repeat directive with $scope.$broadcast()/$scope.$on()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following problem. There is a service which is responsible to store some selected object id. And when a object is selected, $rootScope broadcasts event to notify involved controller.

```
var SelectedObjectFactory = function (objectsFactory, $rootScope) {
        var selectedObjectId;
        var selObjFactory = {};
        selObjFactory.SelectObject = function (objectID) {
           selectedObjectId = objectID
            $rootScope.$broadcast("ObjectSelected", { selectedId: selectedObjectId });
            };
        selObjFactory.GetSelectObjectId = function () {
        return selectedObjectId;
    };
        return selObjFactory;
    };
    SelectedObjectFactory.$inject = ['objectsFactory', '$rootScope'];
    app.factory("selectedObjectFactory", SelectedObjectFactory);
```

**And i use $scope.attachedProperties in view with ng-repeat to create list of properties.**

```
  var FormController = function ($scope, selectedObjectFactory, eventPropertiesFactory) {
      $scope.$on("ObjectSelected", function (event, selectedObject) {
        $scope.attachedProperties =     eventPropertiesFactory.GetPropertiesForEventById(selectedObject.selectedId);
    });
 }

FormController.$inject = ['$scope', 'selectedObjectFactory', 'eventPropertiesFactory'];
angular.module("svgObjectsApp").controller("FormController", FormController);
```

And i use  $scope.attachedProperties in view with ng-repeat to create list of properties.

```
<div class="col-lg-3" ng-controller="FormControler">
    <table>
        <tbody>
             <tr ng-repeat="property in attachedProperties">
                 <td class="col-lg-6 tabletitle">{{property.propertyName}}</td>
                 <td class="col-lg-6"><input  type="text" value={{property .propertyValue}} / >               </td>
              </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

**In controller $scope.$on works fine. I see in developer tool that all variables are updated.**

1. Problem is list in html is not created. I asume that i'm missing
   something about how ng-repeat derictive works with controller, but
   can't find solution in Angular JS documentation.
2. And second question is  good way to use $broadcast() for  informing
   controller about changes in service.

Update:
This is attachedPropertyFactory code:

```
var AttachedPropertiesFactory = function () {
        var propertiesArray = [];
        var propertiesFactory = {};
        propertiesFactory.PutNewPropertiesInArray = PutNewPropertiesInArray;
       propertiesFactory.GetPropertiesForEventById = GetPropertiesForEventById;
       function GetPropertiesForEventById(eventId) {
           selectedProperties = [];
           for (var i = 0; i < propertiesArray.length; i++) {
                if (propertiesArray[i].eventId === eventId) {
                    selectedProperties.push(propertiesArray[i]);
                }
            }
            return selectedProperties;
        }

        function PutNewPropertiesInArray(properties) {
            ClearPropertiesArray();
            for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
                propertiesArray.push(properties[i]);
            }
        };
        function ClearPropertiesArray() {
            propertiesArray.length = 0;
        }

        return propertiesFactory;
    };
AttachedPropertiesFactory.$inject = [];
angular.module("svgObjectsApp").factory("eventPropertiesFactory", AttachedPropertiesFactory);
```

Comment: can you write down the code of eventPropertiesFactory as well. Might be a problem there or you getting data back in $scope. attachedProperties?

Comment: Can you declare $scope.attachProperties as an empty array, before doing the $scope.$on call

Comment: @V31 I have put code of eventPropertyFactory to update of my question.

Comment: @Gabs00 I have try your advice nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this problem. I got this idea after reading folowing article:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html.

I have added $scope.$digest() in event handler. So now my code in FormController looks like this:

```
var FormController = function ($scope, selectedObjectFactory, eventPropertiesFactory) {
       $scope.$on("ObjectSelected", function (event, selectedObject) {
             $scope.attachedProperties =     eventPropertiesFactory.GetPropertiesForEventById(selectedObject.selectedId);    
             $scope.$digest();
        });
}
```

It works for me, but I'm still not sure whether it correct solution or not.